# data changed by adding NSDictionary into NSMutableArray in swift

Tags: swift, nsarray, nsdictionary

```
var arr = NSMutableArray()
var result:NSArray = dbManager.loadDataFromDB(query) 
println("result: \(result)") // print out of result is result: ((11511 ),(11951)) 
for item in products
{
   var jsonDictionary:NSDictionary = NSDictionary(objects:[result], forKeys:["result"]) 
println("jsonDictionary: \(jsonDictionary)") // print out of jsonDictionary is jsonDictionary: {result = ((11511 ),(11951)) ;}
   arr.addObject(jsonDictionary)// !!! here is the error, I have arr: ({result = ();})
println("arr: \(arr)")// !!! here is the error, I have arr: ({result = ();})
}
```

I cant understand why the value changed when I add it in NSArray. I am using Xcode 6, swift. I hope you can help me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How to you determine the results, Please add the `println` statements. Take not that debugger is yet quite raw for Swift and can show wrong values.

Comment: You should get rid of NSMutableArray, NSDictionary and NSArray. Just a nice note...

Comment: Also: Don't use upper case for properties. Rename it to `dictionary`. Upper case `Dictionary` is a defined type. Maybe that solves the issue.

Comment: i update my code, what do you mean by get rid of NSMutableArray? Sorry i am new.

Answer (score 0):

what is the "products" variable?

Why are you iterating over "products". Is the count of products being mutated while being enumerated.

Comment: products is a class I 've created. I'm iterating on it because there must be other codes after adding objects to array that I didn't write down.

Comment: You are iterating over a object of type products which might contain more than 1 object. Are you trying to add the 'jsonDictionary' with objects for the same key "result" in each iteration.